# How to update same column with different values

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table Attributes
(
    id int, 
    AttributeName nvarchar(255), 
    AttributeValue nvarchar(255)
)

insert into Attributes
values
 (1, 'BuiltNo', '001')
,(1, 'ManagerName', 'x')
,(1, 'PlantAddress', 'NY')
,(2, 'BuiltNo', '002')
,(2, 'ManagerName', 'y')
,(2, 'PlantAddress', 'NSW')
,(3, 'BuiltNo', '003')
,(3, 'ManagerName', 'z')
,(3, 'PlantAddress', 'QLD')
```

[image]

I want to update `BuiltNo`, `ManagerName` and `PlantAddress` where `id = 1` in a single update query. Apparently we can not have 2 `where` conditions in the same query hence looking for different solution.

```
update Attributes 
set AttributeValue = '*001'  where AttributeName = 'BuiltNo' ,
set  AttributeValue = '*UpdatedValue'   where AttributeName = 'ManagerName' 
where id = 1
```

Comment: You know how to use a `values` clause with `insert`. Have you tried to `join` on a `values` clause with `update`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `join` on a `values` clause to specify the conditions and new values to apply such as the following:

```sql
update Attributes
set AttributeValue = NewAttributeValue
from dbo.Attributes
join (values
  (1, 'BuiltNo', '*001'),
  (1, 'ManagerName', '*UpdatedValue')
) modifications (id, AttributeName, NewAttributeValue)
  on Attributes.id=modifications.id and Attributes.AttributeName=modifications.AttributeName;
```

Which yields the results:

| id | AttributeName | AttributeValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BuiltNo | *001 |
| 1 | ManagerName | *UpdatedValue |
| 1 | PlantAddress | NY |
| 2 | BuiltNo | 002 |
| 2 | ManagerName | y |
| 2 | PlantAddress | NSW |
| 3 | BuiltNo | 003 |
| 3 | ManagerName | z |
| 3 | PlantAddress | QLD |

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, pass a JSON string

**Example**

```
Declare @I int = 1
Declare @J varchar(max) = '{"BuiltNo":"*001","ManagerName":"*UpdatedValue" }'


Update A
   set AttributeValue =B.Value
 From  Attributes A
 Join ( Select * from openjson(@J) ) B
 On A.id=@I and A.AttributeName=B.[key] collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

**Updated Table**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use `case when` for a simple approach.

```
    UPDATE Attributes 
    SET AttributeValue =  CASE  
                        WHEN AttributeName = 'BuiltNo' THEN '*001'
                        WHEN AttributeName = 'UpdatedValue' THEN 'ManagerName'  
                        
                    END 
    WHERE id = 1 and AttributeName IN ('BuiltNo', 'UpdatedValue')
```

Comment: My first thought as well, but I would expand your WHERE to include ...  AttributeName in ('BuiltNo','ManagerName')  ...  otherwise every row of ID 1 would be updated

Comment: The `ELSE` path is wrong, you are setting `AttributeValue` to `AttributeName`

Comment: @John Cappelletti Thanks I'll edit the changes